# How to include JavaScript in a static block?

Tags: php, javascript, html, magento

I have a static block in the back end with identifier `veri-sign` where in I would like to display the veri-sign logo which when clicked takes the user to the verisign certificate page.

This is my code in the Static Block in the back end

```
       <div id="left-block1-verisign" style="border: 2px solid #f4f5e9; width: 180px; padding: 5px;">
       <p style="font-size: 18px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; margin-left: 8px; color: #4e2488;">Safe &amp; Secure</p>
      <script src="https://seal.verisign.com/getseal?host_name=www.mysite.com&amp;size=S&amp;use_flash=NO&amp;use_transparent=NO&amp;lang=en"></script>
      </div>
```

I am calling this static block in `page.xml` file in left column like this,

```
      <block type="cms/block" name="cms_test_block4">
           <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>veri-sign</block_id></action>
      </block>
```

The block displays fine without the Verisign logo and just the text 'Safe and Secure'. I have gone through many posts on different forums but never really got an answer from there.

I used Firebug to see if it includes my Javascript at all. It includes the `<script>` line but not the javascript inside it which is this,

```
     <script src="https://seal.verisign.com/getseal?host_name=www.mysite.com&size=S& use_flash=NO&use_transparent=NO&lang=en">
    <!--
     dn="www.mysite.com";
     lang="en";
     tpt="opaque";
     vrsn_style="WW";
     splash_url="https://trustsealinfo.verisign.com";
     rStr="";
     seal_url="https://seal.verisign.com";
      u1=splash_url+"/splash?form_file=fdf/splash.fdf&dn="+dn+"&lang="+lang;u2=seal_url+"/getseal?at=0&sealid=2&dn="+dn+"&lang="+lang+rStr;var sopener;function vrsn_splash(){if(sopener&&!sopener.closed){sopener.focus();}else{tbar="location=yes,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=560,height=500";var sw=window.open(u1,'VRSN_Splash',tbar);if(sw){sw.focus();sopener=sw;}}}
     var ver=-1;var v_ua=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();var re=new RegExp("msie ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");if(re.exec(v_ua)!==null){ver=parseFloat(RegExp.$1);}
     var v_old_ie=(v_ua.indexOf("msie")!=-1);if(v_old_ie){v_old_ie=ver<5;}
     function v_mact(e){var s;if(document.addEventListener){s=(e.target.name=="seal");   
     if(s){vrsn_splash();return false;}}else if(document.captureEvents){var tgt=e.target.toString();s=(tgt.indexOf("splash")!=-1);if(s){vrsn_splash();return false;}}
     ......
     N wHOLE LOAD of VERISIGN COde
    -->
   </script>
   <a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:vrsn_splash()">
   <img border="true" alt="Click to Verify - This site has chosen an SSL Certificate to improve Web site security" oncontextmenu="return false;" src="https://seal.verisign.com/getseal?at=0&sealid=2&dn=www.mysite.com&lang=en" name="seal">
   </a>
```

It neither includes the code from the script nor the image and the `<a>` tag.

I dont know if the script needs to be added through page.xml file or not? But if that's the case how will it know that its supposed to be executed from my block.

I am kinda confused here and need some help. I'm sure some one must have successfully done this (including verisign certificate on your magento site), just taht I'm doing thru a Static Block.

I have a twitter feed as well in static block which has external twitter JavaScript which works fine. But the verisign logo doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this thing with another way.

You need to follow this way given below:

1. Call your Static Block to any custom PHTML file.
2. Add your script section in this PHTML file.
3. You can set this PHTML file in Left Column using `Page.xml`.

Hope it will work for you!

Comment: I need to have a static block on every page. Can you specifically tell me where should my custom PHTML file be? I tried your steps but dint do the trick for me. I created `app/design/frontend/default/ats_theme/template/page/html/verisign.phtml` and called my static block in there. I also added the `<script>` bit in the same file. I then wrote this in page.xml `<block type="page/html_verisign" name="verisign" as="verisign" template="page/html/verisign.phtml"/>`. Dint work :(

Comment: please try this -
<block type="core/template" name="verisign" as="verisign" template="page/html/verisign.phtml"/>

Comment: @Anx - Can you please add a code sample for all the given steps? E.g. 1) How to call Static Block to any custom PHTML file, 3) How to set the PHTML file using `Page.xml`? I have asked almost [same question here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18606738/1369235). You can answer there too if you know. Thanks

Comment: Please follow the link http://magentostriker.blogspot.in/2012/02/most-frequently-used-functions-in.html . Hope it would help. Thanks.