# Add <style> and <script> in Magento static block

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magento, static-block

I have a static block (Identifier is `mega_menu`)

It has some code like this:

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
     <li data-submenu-id="submenu-patas">
         <div id="submenu-patas" class="popover">
            <h3 class="popover-title">Patas</h3>
            <div class="popover-content"><img src="img/patas.png"></div>
         </div>
     </li>
     <li data-submenu-id="submenu-snub-nosed">
         <div id="submenu-snub-nosed" class="popover">
            <h3 class="popover-title">Golden Snub-Nosed</h3>
            <div class="popover-content"><img src="img/snub-nosed.png"></div>
         </div>
     </li>
</ul>
```

In the normal html file (from where I got this code) there are some styles and it's references like this:

```css
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">  --<--Reference
<style>
  body {
    padding-top: 60px;
  }
</style>
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">  --<--Reference
<style>
    .navbar .popover {
        width: 400px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
        border-top-left-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

And also some scripts and it's references like this:

```js
<script src="../jquery.menu-aim.js" type="text/javascript"></script> --<Reference
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> --<--Reference
<script>
    var $menu = $(".dropdown-menu");
    .
    .
    .
    $(document).click(function() {
        // Simply hide the submenu on any click. Again, this is just a hacked
        // together menu/submenu structure to show the use of jQuery-menu-aim.
        $(".popover").css("display", "none");
        $("a.maintainHover").removeClass("maintainHover");
    });
</script>
```

So my question is:

Can I these styles and scripts directly in static block?
If no how can I add these styles and script with work for particular static block (e.g. `mega_menu` here)?

<sub>PS: Magento noob here</sub>

Comment: make new phtml file and call phtml file from static block..

Comment: @Keyur - You mean I can add these styles and scripts on `phtml` file? If yes How to call `phtml` file from the static block? (Add it as your answer.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

call phtml file from static block

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/html/YOUR_FILE_NAME.phtml"}}
```

and write your code in YOUR_FILE_NAME.phtml

Comment: Can we write every code in the `phtml` file same as `html`? (i.e. html, css and javascript in one file)

Comment: +1 Just another doubt: Is there any specific path where I store this phtml file?

Comment: no,,,you can store your phtml in any folder but within app>design>froentend>THEME_NAME>template folder

Comment: app/design/frontend/<package name>/<theme name>/ path to your phtml

ex
app/design/frontend/base/default/page/html/xx.phtml

Comment: How do I access CSS file from skin/frontend/<My Package>/<My Template>/css/ from this phtml file?